# kineticjs extending the shape class causing uncaught range error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

This is my first time posting and I've looked as best I could for an answer to this question. I have come up empty handed.

Previously I was using 3.10.2 of kineticJS.  I have updated the library to use 4.1.2 which is the latest as of today.  I've experienced several errors most of which I have resolved, however, I've reached a dead end.

Here is the error I get in my js file.  I don't know where in the js it is happening.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
  Kinetic.Node.getParent
  Kinetic.Node.getStage
  Kinetic.Node.getStage
  .....
```

`Kinetic.Node.getStage` repeats 100+ times after that.

I have reasons to believe it has to do with how I am modifying the prototype of `Kinetic.Shape` [because of this article](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/99)

```
function Datapoint() {
 this.uv = 0;
 this.royalblue = 0;
 this.royalblue2 = 0;
 this.presetId = 0;
 this.blue = 0;
 this.coolwhite = 0;
 this.green = 0;
 this.hyperred = 0;
 this.brightness = 0;
 this.clouds = 0;
 this.storms = 0;
 this.pointTime = new Date();
 this.id = 0;
 this.profileId = 0;
 this.intensity = 0;
 this.xCoord = 0;
 this.yCoord = 0;
 this.isStartNight = false;
 this.isStartDay = false;
 this.isNight = false
 this.isDay = false;
 this.isNatural = false;
}

//Modify the shape object
var DatapointObject = Kinetic.Shape;
DatapointObject.prototype.Datapoint;
```

Then, I attempt to create a point the standard way.

```
var point = Kinetic.Circle({<config object>});
```

I believe that this may be the source of my error. If so, how do I fix it?

If this isn't the source of my error, can anyone lend some advice that may help me to deduce where exactly the issue is?

Comment: Usualy, a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error is caused by the fact that you repeat something too much so it causes memory leaks. Try to add some `console.log()` at specific positions and check if those are repeated more than 100 times in your debugging console (Firebug/Chrome inspector)

Comment: I added some breakpoints at the very top of the js, way before where I thought the initial error was.  Turns out that my code was sloppy above and I was adding a layer to itself, rather than the stage.  Thanks for the quick response @Ghillied

Comment: No problem sir. I am glad you fixed the problem in a short timespan!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this error is also caused by adding a layer to itself.  Like so:

```
myLayer.add(myLayer);  //<--doesn't make any sense
```

This should be

```
myStage.add(myLayer); //<-- fixed
```